# Pandoc: Convert Markdown to HTML *without* any HTML attributes

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc, converters

Is there a way to tell Pandoc to convert Markdown to HTML in such a way that generates only plain HTML tags without any attributes/classes?

Example:

**Current Pandoc output**

```
<pre class="sourceCode bash">
  <code class="sourceCode bash">
      TEXT
  </code>
</pre>
```

**Desired Pandoc output**

```
<pre>
  <code>
      TEXT
  </code>
</pre>
```

I browsed the official documentation but didn't find any options to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: is your issue only with code blocks, or..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in option, but you can use a simple [filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to remove all attributes and classes. Save the following to a file `remove-attr.lua` and call pandoc with `--lua-filter=remove-attr.lua`.

```lua
function remove_attr (x)
  if x.attr then
    x.attr = pandoc.Attr()
    return x
  end
end

return {{Inline = remove_attr, Block = remove_attr}}
```